# Notepad++ doesn't color String type in my programs, why?

Tags: string, colors, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I was looking at some code i've written, an example from a book:

```
public class Acquisto {
    private String nome;
    private int dimGruppo;
    private double prezzoGruppo;
    private int articoliAcquistati;
```

Well, Notepad++ doesn't color the String type like it does with the other types (int, char).
Is it normal ? Or is it because i moved all my documents from C: to D:, my hard disk ?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor. Not an IDE. You should try using a proper IDE. You might like it. I know I do.

Comment: This is not the right forum for this question. This is a software application specific question. The answer is you have to select a language while you have your page open.

Comment: Did you set the Language of the file to Java?

Answer (score 2):

Since String is a java class not any reserve keyword, maybe that's the reason it's not showing any color on Notepad++

Try words like below, it will show in colors in notepad++ as those are the reserve keywords :

```
    switch 
    strictfp
    short
    static
    synchronized
    super
```

While String wouldn't show as it's a predefined class in java.lang package

```
String str = "ABC";
```